# Pandas converting the columns with '0%' as object and not reading as float

Tags: pandas

While reading an excel into data frames, by default the percentage values should get converted to `float`, but when there is a value 0 in any of the rows, `pandas` reads it as `object` by default.

Could any one please suggest a way around for reading the column as `float`?

When I try to convert using converters or `astype` function, I get the following error `could not convert string to float: '0%'`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove "%" from your dataset

```
df['column_name'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('%','')).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could provide a sample of your data (much easier for us to test the code). However, as far as I can tell from the error, the problem comes from the percentage sign that `pandas` classifies as a string and therefore sets the entire column as an `object`.
You can remove `%` through `str.replace` and then use the `astype` function.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'perc': ['100%', '24%', '2%']})
df['perc'] = df['perc'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```